# Firebase: How to structure data for the most shared posts in the last n days?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Let's assume there is a blog and you would like to list the most liked or shared posts for today, the last 7 days and the last 30 days.

The solution for today is rather easy:

```
-mostSharedPostsForToday
   -2018-10-08
       -$postId
           -numberOfShares
```

Then the query would observe `mostSharedPostsForToday/2018-10-08` for today's most shared posts ordered by child `numberOfShares`.

But how to structure the data for the most shared posts in the past n days?

One solution I can think of is to write a cloud function that populates the node `mostSharedPostsForThePastNDays` on a daily basis. But it seems cumbersome to me. Isn't there a more efficient way?

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments of the 1st answer pagination should be supported to save traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I recomand you to use another approach. In stead of using the date as your node, remove that node and add a `TIMESTAMP` for each post like this:

```
-mostSharedPostsForToday
   -$postId
       - TIMESTAMP: 2018-10-08
       - numberOfShares: 10
```

To know how many shared you have in a single day, you need to use the following code:

```
rootRef.child("mostSharedPostsForToday").child(postId).orderByChild("TIMESTAMP").equalsTo("2018-10-08");
```

And if you want an interval please use the following code:

```
rootRef.child("mostSharedPostsForToday").child(postId).orderByChild("TIMESTAMP").startAt("2018-10-08").endAt("2018-10-15");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with your approach I can't sort by the number of shares since Firebase does not support ordering by multiple values. Sorting would be helpful for pagination, e.g. first show only the top 5 and then the next 5 and so on.

Comment: You cannot use multiple ordering methods but you still can achieve this. Please see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&index=4&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s=5#t=9m03s). In your case you need to use: `TIMESTAMP_numberOfShares`.

Comment: Tried it with `TIMESTAMP_numberOfShares` (e.g. `2018-01-01_100`), unfortunately there is no way to sort in descending order. Negating the value is not possible, since it is of type string.