# Firebase: Is there a difference between client transactions and cloud function transactions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616271/firebase-how-to-structure-data-for-the-most-shared-posts-in-the-last-n-days) I am trying to find a way to show trending posts with Firebase.

Since I see no other way to solve this, I've decided to go with redundancy:

```
-trendingToday
    -$date
        -$postId
            -numberOfLikes // negative number for descending order

-trendingMonth
    -$date
        -$postId
            -numberOfLikes // negative number for descending order
```

When a user likes a post, first `trendingToday/$date/$postId/numberOfLikes` gets decreased by 1 with a transaction. Then there should be a `for-loop` to decrease the number in `trendingMonth/$date/$postId/numberOfLikes` where `$date` loops through the next 30 days. This should also be performed with transactions.

Now the question is: Am I better off with doing this logic on the client or is it preferable to solve this with cloud functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to perform a lot of items of work on the client, there is a chance that the work may not all complete if the user kills the app or it loses connectivity or some other interruption.

A Cloud Function is highly *unlikey* to get interrupted during its course of execution, so there is a much better chance of all your transactions completing consistently.